# allowedLateness on Global Window custom trigger

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have created a custom trigger and processing function for my event stream.

```
DataStream<DynamoDBRow> dynamoDBRows =
    sensorEvents
        .keyBy("id")
        .window(GlobalWindows.create())
        .trigger(new MyCustomTrigger())
        .allowedLateness(Time.minutes(1)) # Note
        .process(new MyCustomWindowProcessFunction());
```

My trigger is based on an event parameter. Once the event-end signal is received, the *MyCustomWindowProcessFunction()* is applied on the window elements.

```
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomTrigger extends Trigger<SensorEvent, GlobalWindow> {

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onElement(SensorEvent element, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    if (element.isEventEnd() == true) {
      return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
    }

    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear(GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {}
}
```

There could be few sensor data, that could come even after the Trigger. So I added `.allowedLateness(Time.minutes(1))`, to ensure that, those events are not missed out, while processing.

In my case, **allowedLateness** is not working.

After going through the documents, I found this

[image: allowedLateness is not applicable for Global Window]

How can I include **allowedLateness** in GlobalWindow?

**Note**: I also tried setting environment Time Characteristic

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);
```

**Update: 20-02-2020**

Currently thinking of the below approach. (Not working so far)

```
@Slf4j
public class JourneyTrigger extends Trigger<SensorEvent, GlobalWindow> {

  private final long allowedLatenessMillis;

  public JourneyTrigger(Time allowedLateness) {
    this.allowedLatenessMillis = allowedLateness.toMilliseconds();
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onElement(SensorEvent element, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    if (element.isEventEnd() == true) {
      log.info("Timer started with allowedLatenessMillis " + allowedLatenessMillis);
      ctx.registerEventTimeTimer(System.currentTimeMillis() + allowedLatenessMillis);
    }

    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.info("onEvenTime called at "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
    return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
  }


  @Override
  public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear(GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to achieve my requirement using the below custom trigger.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.TriggerResult;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.GlobalWindow;

@Slf4j
public class JourneyTrigger extends Trigger<SensorEvent, GlobalWindow> {

  private final long allowedLatenessMillis;

  public JourneyTrigger(Time allowedLateness) {
    this.allowedLatenessMillis = allowedLateness.toMilliseconds();
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onElement(SensorEvent element, long timestamp, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    if (element.isEventEnd()==true) {
      log.info("Timer started with allowedLatenessMillis " + allowedLatenessMillis);
      ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(System.currentTimeMillis() + allowedLatenessMillis);
    }

    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    log.info("onProcessingTime called at "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
    return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
  }

  @Override
  public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
  }



  @Override
  public void clear(GlobalWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {}
}
```

Also in the `Driver.java` class, set environment Time Characteristic

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't see a reason to use the `GlobalWindow` here. You could just use the `KeyedProcessFunction` that would serve the same purpose as Your `Trigger`, basically, it would gather all elements from the beginning of the event till the end of the event into the `ListState` and then when You receive the `isEventEnd()==true`, You could simply schedule the `EventTime` timer that would fire after a minute and would emit the results gathered inside `ListState`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, how would I purge the window data? In my case, the sensor-stop signal means, sensor stopped sending data for the current interval. I need to apply aggregation logic and then save the data to DB. Once the sensor is turned on again, it sends a new set of data with the same `id`. In that window, I don't want past sensor data. That was the reason for choosing Global Window.

Comment: Yeah, but nothing stops You from removing all elements from the given `ListState` after the element is emitted :) Since it would be keyed state, this means that You would basically purge all the data for this particular key.